# Change package folder to different folder

Tags: windows-xp, sublimetext2

I am installing Sublime Text 2 at my work on a Windows XP machine, which sets the package folder  to `%APPDATA%\Sublime Text 2\Packages`.

I need to change this to a different folder because this exceeds my profile storage space. Can this be changed via Sublime or do I have to use symbolic link to a different directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Too bad this isn't supported (as of Sublime Text 2.1) through configuration, but creating a directory symbolic link works perfectly.

For this I used the [junction tool](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896768.aspx) from the [sysinternals suite](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb842062). Runs on Windows XP and higher or Windows Server 2003 and higher.

Answer (score 0):

Symbolic link is your best bet, I haven't seen or heard of changing the location of the packages folder before.